# Why does this low-score question not show up at the bottom of questions sorted by votes?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

[This question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/47590/would-it-harm-my-phd-application-if-a-female-professor-writes-me-a-reference) has a (deserved) score of -12.  Yet if I search for [all questions sorted by votes](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions?page=199&sort=votes) and scroll to the very last page, it does not show up; the lowest non-closed question is [this question with +5-15=-10](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44816/has-there-ever-been-a-paper-written-by-three-people-with-last-names-starting-wit]).  Why don't I see the -12 question there?

Comment: I just downvoted the [question with -10 score](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44816/has-there-ever-been-a-paper-written-by-three-people-with-last-names-starting-wit%5D) so that it has a -11 score and it has now been removed from the list of all questions sorted by votes.

Comment: Right now the [question with 0-12=-12 score](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/47590/64) is listed on the 7th page of the newest questions list.

Comment: It has happened before http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95408/sorting-questions-by-votes-is-broken but SE thinks it is fixed. I noticed it a few months ago but never followed up on it.

Comment: I just checked this out and I do see the question at the bottom of the list. Can you repro? If not, I'm going to assume it was just caching.

Comment: @Pops I cannot reproduce it now.